# Copy a formula down a dynamic column (without header)

Tags: excel, vba, range, copying, dynamic-columns

I have table which will be updated on a regular basis. As there will be columns inserted, I don't have a fixed range.

I found a way to look for a certain Value ("x") and select the cell below. I managed to update all necessary formulas and print them in cell below the header.
It works until the point of copying.

I tried to copy the formula down the column:

```
Sub Sum_three_months()

    Set Three_months = Range("A1:ZZ10000").Find("x")
    Three_months.Select
    FormularCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count, _
    Selection.Columns.Count).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-0]C[-4]:R[-0]C[-2])"
    
    Sum_six_months ' starts the next update, but has the same format as above
End Sub
```

I tried `Autofill` and `FillDown` but with Autofill I get an error with the range/selected cell and with Filldown it just copies the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub Sum_three_months()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, Three_months As Range, rngLast As Range, x As String, lastCol As Long
 
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  x = "x" 'use here your search string...
  Set Three_months = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(1, lastCol)).Find(x)
  If Not Three_months Is Nothing Then
      Set rngLast = sh.Cells(sh.Cells(Rows.count, Three_months.Offset(0, -4).Column).End(xlUp).row, Three_months.Column)
    
      sh.Range(Three_months.Offset(1, 0), rngLast).formula = _
                   "=SUM(" & sh.Range(Three_months.Offset(1, -4), Three_months.Offset(1, -2)).address(0, 0) & ")"
  Else
     MsgBox "Not a ""x"" range could be found...": Exit Sub
  End If
    
 Sum_six_months ' starts the next update, but has the same format as above
End Sub
```

Comment: @Djerun: Did you keep the variable declarations as I used in the code? Anyhow, please refresh the page (this one) and copy the last version, where all ranges are referenced to the same sheet (active sheet in my code, but you can choose the one you need). I used your code bases, but it would be good to check if  `Three_months` is not nothing... I will adapt the code...

Comment: Not exactly. Your code replace´s my header with the sum of the cells ```C2:E2``` but I thats not the cells I need and I dont´t get the formulars copied down either... Edit: I copied your code into my workbook and executed it.

Comment: @Djerun: Yes, sorry... I used a particular case I tested. Please, refresh the page and try using the updated code. Do you still receive the error on that code line?

Comment: Okay, now your the sum is in the right cell. But  it doesn´t copy down the column and the ```Range("C2:E2") is wrong. It needs to take the sum of  three cells next to it´s left cell. So if the formular is in "F2" it shall skip "E2" and take the sum of "B2:D2" . That´s why I used  ```(R[-0]C[-4]:R[-0]C[-2]``` Edit: I´ll try it!

Comment: @Djerun: Try the updated code, please. In fact, did you check my code using Offset (-4 and -2)? Does your sheet  have any row down to the "x" cell? If not, according to what column to calculate what to be "down"?

Comment: @Djerun: Try the updated code, please. In fact, did you check my code using Offset (-4 and -2)? Does your sheet  have any row down to the "x" cell? If not, according to what column to calculate what to be "down"? According to your question meaning, I supposed that there are rows down and they will be rewritten. If not, please specify based on what column should the code calculate the last row to fill down.

Comment: Could I sent you an example-file to your mailadress I see in your Profile? Maybe thats easier for you to understand than my sloppy explanation...

Comment: @Djerun: It looks I have a problem with my Outlook. Since I will solve it, please try the updated code. It now calculates the last row to be filled according to the last cell in `Offset(0, -4)`... I receive it and my last code does exactly what (I understand) you need. Did you test it? And now I can see that your search string is in the first row. Will it always be in the first row?